# Azure DevOps Git prevent work on same project

Tags: git, azure

Trying to get started with Azure DevOps Repositories (Git) and I could not find an answer as to how can I prevent someone checking out code that is already checked by a different user.
For ex: let's say User1 works on project 1 - it will bring it down to its local machine and start making important changes.
At the same time, let's say User2 check out the same project. At this point user2 is not aware that User1 is working on Project1.

With previous version control if a project was checked out you could see that ... is it possible with Azure Dev Ops? Or can we prevent a checkout?

Appreciate the help.
AV

Comment: Git's design forbids you to forbid someone else from doing work. You definitely cannot *stop* them. Some other system might allow you to warn them; Git does not. Git assumes that this kind of parallel development is *good*, and should be encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

This is specifically the opposite of how Git is supposed to work, and as such there is no way to do it.  In order to work on a project located on a remote system, you must clone it to your local system.  Once that clone has been made, it is independent of the remote system and the user can make changes to it at any point without further contact with the server.

The general approach to development with Git is that each user is free to work on changes at the same time, and if a central server is used, like in this case, changes from multiple users can be merged independently because each user can develop their own feature branches which can merge when they're ready.  This functionality is required for nearly all non-trivial projects, since it isn't reasonable to lock out tens, hundreds, or thousands of other developers just because one person is working on the code.